# Ошибка в импорт

Tags: python

[image]

Библиотеку speedtest-cli я поставил. Но всё равно ошибка в импорте

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Код, ошибки и прочие причины и следствия лучше оформлять в виде текста, чтобы отвечающему было проще разобраться в причине

Comment: @ViktorTomilov он про то, что импорт красным подчеркивает

Comment: Вот у вас там справа внизу выбрано окружение `Python 3.10 (ap1k)`, вы библиотеку точно именно в это окружение ставили, а не в какое-то другое? Нужно выбрать то же окружение, куда ставили.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте: import speedtest

Доп. источник:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/test-internet-speed-using-python/

Comment: Нет разницы - использовать `from speedtest import Speedtest` потом например `download = Speedtest().download()` или `import speedtest` потом `download = speedtest.Speedtest().download()`. К проблеме в вопросе это никак не отноится.

Answer (score 0):

перед импортированием из модуля чего либо стоит убедиться что вы импортировали сам модуль